# insertMany drop down mongodb service

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have API, where I get datas. I use `mongoose` to save it into my local MongoDB. Each time when I save, I create dynamically new `model` and use `insertMany` on it:

```
const data = result.Data;
const newCollectionName = `tab_${name.toLowerCase()}`;
const Schema = new mongoose.Schema({}, { strict: false });
const TAB = mongoose.model(newCollectionName, Schema);
return TAB.collection.drop(() => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line
  const clearJSONs = Object.values(data)
    .filter(x => typeof x === 'object');

  return TAB.insertMany(clearJSONs, (err, result2) => {
    // console.log(result2);
    res.json({ success: true });
  });
});
```

But... later, when all almost complete, my mongoose service falls down ... And... I even dont know what to do.

---

upd. mongo log:

```
2018-06-17T13:43:09.883+0300 E STORAGE  [conn58] WiredTiger error (24) [1529232189:883394][4799:0x7f9fe1d30700], WT_SESSION.create: /var/lib/mongodb/: directory-sync: open: Too many open files
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in `ulimits` of the system. The best solution was described [by this guy](https://sskaje.me/systemd-ulimit/)